# https://localhost:1337 gives "not trusted" error on ubuntu webserver, but domain doesn't

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, server

Im currently trying to connect to my node server via ssl from the webserver running the node server.

Accessing https://my-website.com:1337 works both from my webserver and from a remote machine.

However accessing https://localhost:1337 gives me a "not trusted" error when accessed from my webserver.
Im running ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your SSL certificate is only valid for my-website.com and not valid for https://localhost:1337. That's why you're getting the not trusted error.

Comment: Thought they shared a certifcate, currently trying to add them, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added localhost in the subjectalternativename section of the ssl cert?

Does it give you any failure message when connecting to localhost?

Comment: Wouldn't adding "localhost" as a SAN only be available with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't have to be self signed, it just cannot be signed by an internet certificate authority.  You can create your own CA and sign it.  A better option might be to access https://127.0.0.1:1337 instead of https://localhost:1337